# Как отследить выполнение курлом GET-запроса?

Tags: curl, php

Если можно, покажите скрин фаербага.

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) 
{
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:7887/?action=send?&acees=true');

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($out);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo('1');
}
else
{
    echo('1');
}
?>
```

Comment: Может снифером?

Comment: wireshark в помощь